# android and for loop

Tags: android, for-loop

I have a problem with a for loop.
this is my code

```
int i;
int from= Integer.valueOf(field_from.getText().toString());
int to  = Integer.valueOf(field_to.getText().toString());
Log.d("wec", "from->"+from+" to->"+to);
for(i=from;  from < to; i++){
  Log.d("wec", "i->"+i);
}
```

The value of field_from is 1 and the value of field_to is 10
When i run the script the application be crazy because start a loop from 100 to infinite

Anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your comparison logic is wrong in for loop

instead of  ( from < to)
you should have (i < to)  in for loop

Answer (score 3):

```
for(i=from;  from < to; i++)
```

You are iterating over the condition `from < to`. Neither of the two variables change in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(i=from;  i < to; i++){
  Log.d("wec", "i->"+i);
```

use this.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong condition in the for loop, should be `i < to`, not `from < to`.